# Python pandas outputs floats instead of integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to save a matrix (which is very very sparse with millions of zeros and a few another numbers) as pandas dataframe to the .csv file, But dataframe save 0's as 0.0 (float instead of integer) and therefore, the file becomes very large. So i want to save 0.0's as 0's to reduce output .csv file size.
I am trying something like:

```
import pandas
table = [[0.88, 4], [0, 0.5]]
pd = pandas.DataFrame(table, columns = ['C1', 'C2'])
pd.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
pd
```

And get output:

```
    C1      C2
0   0.88    4.0
1   0.00    0.5
```

But I want the output to be as follows:

```
    C1      C2
0   0.88    4
1   0       0.5
```

Comment: try adding `dtype=object` to your DataFrame constructor

Comment: @Chris, Unexpectedly, it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, yes it does ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with sparse data, I guess that some columns may be only zeros. If you identify any column with only zero, you can convert it to `int` directly with `astype`. It will guarantee to you that zero will be saved in .csv file.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware with a method to change only some values in a column.

I do have an alternative suggestion. When representing sparse objects, you can save only (x,y,value) (this example is for sparse matrix but can be extended) instead of whole dataframe. It's a bit hard to tell exactly how to do it without knowing what your data looks like. Just know you can represent it more effectively, then save it to .csv or dump it with pickle.